# Linq Pivot Using GridView

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create pivot using Linq. But below code runs but doesn't show any output using GridView. Is there anything else to do?? It will generate an ATTENDANCE report with month.

```
 public void pivot()
        {
            List<AttTime> con = new List<AttTime>();

            var we = con.GroupBy(c => c.EmpID)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        UserID = g.Key,
                        Jan = g.Where(c => c.CheckTime.Month == 2).Sum(c => c.EmpID),
                        Feb = g.Where(c => c.CheckTime.Month == 4).Sum(c => c.EmpID)
                    }).ToList();

            GridView2.DataSource = we;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: does we is empty after linq operation?

Comment: It seems so. No output is shown. Any suggestion??

Comment: hmm check it out the we.count in quick watch, see is there any data into it?

Comment: Ohhh there is nothing in your con data